# Switch directory in a docker container within Vertex

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines

I have a DBT docker container.

The WORKDIR is set to `dbt/client/client_name`.

I am easily able to run commands within the docker container using `kfp.components.load_component_from_text()`

However, somewhere along the line I need to switch directories to run other commands, the directory I am attempting to switch to is `dbt/client/client_name_raw`. What command can I use within my `kfp.components.load_component_from_text()` in order to switch to that directory?

I have already tried the following:

```py
    @staticmethod
    def run_seed(client_name_raw, dbt_image_uri, target):
        run_seed = kfp.components.load_component_from_text(f'''
           name: DBT Client Seed
           implementation:
                container:
                  image: {dbt_image_uri}
                  command: ["cd" , "../{client_name_raw}", "dbt", "seed", "--target", "{target}"]
                ''')()
        return run_seed
```

Vertex gives me the following error message

```
"The replica workerpool0-0 exited with a non-zero status of 128. Termination reason: StartError. 
 Termination log message: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "cd": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
To find out more about why your job exited please check the logs:"
```

Seems like Vertex/kfp doesn't know how to interpret "cd" in this context. Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution.

I did it like this

```py
    @staticmethod
    def run_seed(client_name_raw, dbt_image_uri, target):
        run_seed = kfp.components.load_component_from_text(f'''
           name: DBT Client Seed
           implementation:
                container:
                  image: {dbt_image_uri}
                  command: ["bash", "-c", "cd ../{client_name_raw} && dbt deps && dbt seed --target {target}"]
                ''')()
        return run_seed
```

Hope it helps someone who encounters the same issue in future